# JavaFX ActionEvent Rectangle

Tags: java, user-interface, javafx, action

In short:

I'm working on creating a card game with AI, and GUI. The User's hand is displayed on the game play interface, I have yet to complete the interface but I intend on adding a card face Image to rectangles on screen. Rather than having 5 nearly identical methods, I found a similar post and I'm attempting to implement the same idea. However, I ran into something unexpected. Here's the related code from my controller class:

```
/** This is where the players hand will be displayed. */
@FXML
private Rectangle card1, card2, card3, card4, card5;

public void playThisCard(final ActionEvent event) {
    if (event.getSource() == card1) {
        System.out.println("played card 1");
    } else if (event.getSource() == card2) {
        System.out.println("played card 2");
    } else if (event.getSource() == card3) {
        System.out.println("played card 3");
    } else if (event.getSource() == card4) {
        System.out.println("played card 4");
    } else if (event.getSource() == card5) {
        System.out.println("played card 5");
    } else {
        System.out.println("no card played");
    }
}
```

The UI was built in Scene Builder, hence the FXML tag on the Rectangles, the controller is correctly binded, and I've successfully gotten other methods to execute on user input to controls.

```
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: argument type mismatch
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
at sun.reflect.misc.Trampoline.invoke(MethodUtil.java:71)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor1.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
at sun.reflect.misc.MethodUtil.invoke(MethodUtil.java:275)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$MethodHandler.invoke(FXMLLoader.java:1769)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ControllerMethodEventHandler.handle(FXMLLoader.java:1657)
at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:86)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:54)
at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
at javafx.scene.Scene$ClickGenerator.postProcess(Scene.java:3470)
at javafx.scene.Scene$ClickGenerator.access$8100(Scene.java:3398)
at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.process(Scene.java:3766)
at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.access$1500(Scene.java:3485)
at javafx.scene.Scene.impl_processMouseEvent(Scene.java:1762)
at javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePeerListener.mouseEvent(Scene.java:2494)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:352)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:275)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.lambda$handleMouseEvent$355(GlassViewEventHandler.java:388)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.runWithoutRenderLock(QuantumToolkit.java:389)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.handleMouseEvent(GlassViewEventHandler.java:387)
at com.sun.glass.ui.View.handleMouseEvent(View.java:555)
at com.sun.glass.ui.View.notifyMouse(View.java:937)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to handle mouse clicks on `Rectangle`s you can use the [`onMouseClickedProperty`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/Node.html#onMouseClickedProperty).

So I guess in your FXML file you have something like this:

```
onMouseClicked="#playThisCard"
```

But if you take a look on the signature of the mentioned property:

```
public final ObjectProperty<EventHandler<? super MouseEvent>> onMouseClickedProperty
```

you will see it will not pass an `ActionEvent` but a `MouseEvent`, therefore

```
public void playThisCard(final MouseEvent event)
```

is the correct signature to handle events got from a mouse click.

Comment: Ahh okay that makes sense. First time with JavaFX and Scene Builder, using onAction="<method-name>" on the rest of my buttons in the UI, but that wasn't displayed as an available option in SB. Using onMouseRelease=